# where to put business logic in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

the business logic is placed  in the ViewModel in almost all the examples and tutorials I have found. I did some research about it but I am still having trouble because I can't find the model itself and the ViewModel looks like doing everything. some opinions suggested that the model is a server side entity in KO. any clarification will be helpful.

Comment: In the "ideal" version of a model/view/controller scenario, you just might observe that there really IS NO "single place for" 'business' logic.  The real purpose (IMHO) of these libraries is to create an effective *user interface,* and nothing more.  If the task really does concern "the business," the rule and the enforcement of it probably doesn't belong in JavaScript, nor on the *client* side.  Servers ought be making business decisions, partly because *server*-side code is "out of reach."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2.0 is moving towards components by business function rather than by type of output (.js, .html, .css etc)

Knockout is not prescriptive, so you also follow this structure, and also note that Knockout was into observables a long time ago.

The trend to move to backend apis also helps decouple the technology and make it more about business objectives.

I tend to use central service providers to provide the glue between components and api, but postbox allows knockout components to chatter amongst themselves and provide another pattern.